# Service losing bind (mBoundService = null)

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, service

I've got a working version with a Fragment pasing json string to the main activity which has a tcp socket service bound to it:

Main_Activity:

```
...

 private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mBoundService = ((Socket_Service.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBoundService = null;
            Log.d("TCP Client: Main_Activity", "onServiceDisconnected called!");
        }
    };

    ...
        public void writeByte(String jsonObject) {
            if (mBoundService != null) {
                mBoundService.sendMessage(jsonObject);
            }
        }
    ...
```

Fragment:

```
...
Main_Activity activity = (Main_Activity) getActivity();
        activity.writeByte(jsonObject.toString()); 
...
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'd like to create a separate class (no fragment) to create the json string, pass it to the Main_Activity which passes it to the service. I did that, but it's not working, because mBoundService gets the value "null" and cant pass anything to the service anymore.

Fragment:

```
JSON pwmJASON = new JSON();
        pwmJASON.cratePWMJSON(PWM1,PWM2,PWM3,PWM4,PWM5,PWM6,PWM7);
```

JSON.class:

```
package de.l.LED.control.background;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import de.l.LED.control.Main_Activity;


public class JSON extends Main_Activity{

    public void cratePWMJSON(int PWM1, int PWM2, int PWM3, int PWM4, int PWM5, int PWM6, int PWM7){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        try {
            //jsonArray.put("");
            jsonArray.put(PWM1 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM2 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM3 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM4 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM5 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM6 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM7 * 64);
            jsonObject.put("PWMs", jsonArray); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("JSO", "Received JSON String: " + jsonObject.toString());
        Main_Activity activity = new Main_Activity();
        activity.writeByte(jsonObject.toString());
    }

}
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: in which cases your service should get stopped? can it stop itself, does your activity stops it sometimes?

Comment: Yes, ive got a separate button to unbind and stop the service as I wish. mBoundService is getting null value by it self somehow. The only thing I changed is, dong the json part in separate class.

Comment: Where do you need to call `pwmJASON.cratePWMJSON()`? From your fragment or from some other class?

Comment: I need to call it from the fragment which is creating the PWM values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose to use this:

```
public class JsonHelper{

    public static String cratePWMJSON(int PWM1, int PWM2, int PWM3, int PWM4, int PWM5, int PWM6, int PWM7){
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        try {
            //jsonArray.put("");
            jsonArray.put(PWM1 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM2 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM3 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM4 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM5 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM6 * 64);
            jsonArray.put(PWM7 * 64);
            jsonObject.put("PWMs", jsonArray); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("JSO", "Received JSON String: " + jsonObject.toString());
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment you can call it like:

```
String pwmJsonAsString = JsonHelper().cratePWMJSON(PWM1,PWM2,PWM3,PWM4,PWM5,PWM6,PWM7);
Main_Activity activity = (Main_Activity) getActivity();
activity.writeByte(pwmJsonAsString);
```

Comment: Yes, I have got some ideas why it did not work. One thing is that you are trying to instantiate activities directly, like `Main_Activity activity = new Main_Activity();`. You should not do this, as this is task that Android takes care of. By creating new Main_Activity you are trying to call activity.writeByte() on new instance that is not bound to any service. The other thing is that if you want to pass data between activities there are other ways. Search for 'passing data between activities'. Just a hint: one way to do is with intents. However you don't need multiple activities for your case.